Usage of Node JS fs.readFileSync() Method in online editor fails
I'm trying to read the data.json file but I get the error message "Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/data.json'" and I don't know how to solve this issue.
I'm using this online editor: Playcode
Hint: In my Visual Studio Editor it's working - but in the mentioned online editor there I have the issue. How can I solve this issue with the online editor?
See the screenshot with my code and the error message:

And for simplicity the code, if needed...
"use strict"

const fs = require("fs")
const data = fs.readFileSync("data.json",{encoding: "utf-8"})

Also the data.json file
[
  {"Carname": "Chevrolet", "Horsepower": 150, "color": "green"},
  {"Carname": "Mazda", "Horsepower": 220, "color": "red"}
]

Many thanks in advance for your help!

These online editors have a special enviroment, not a normal file system. It seems that in playcode.io you can write files, and then read them again, but apparently they are stored in some special location, not where your source files are stored. I would assume you can not read the files which you have created in the "FILES" panel.
